# When starting a new intent I get a window leak error from async task that has already completed

Tags: android

I am very new to android and would really appreciate the feedback.

My program executes a basic local database transaction through an async task.
The task is passed the object (who's info will be stored) and a Interface which triggered once the db operation is complete.

Util - General class containing createProgressDialog code:

```
public class General {
    public static boolean hasNetworkConnection(Context c){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    public static ProgressDialog createProgressDialog(Context c, String message){
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(c, R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage(message);
        progressDialog.show();

        return progressDialog;
    }

    public static void createDatePicker(FragmentActivity activity, DatePicker.DatePickerInterface callback){
        DatePicker d = DatePicker.newInstance(callback);
        d.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");
}
}
```

Async class:

```
public class RetrieveStudentInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
private ServerDatabaseHelper serverDatabaseHelper;
private LocalDatabaseHelper localDatabaseHelper;

private Context context;
private long userId;
private MainCallback callback;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private String message;

public RetrieveStudentInfo(ServerDatabaseHelper serverDatabaseHelper, LocalDatabaseHelper localDatabaseHelper, Context c, long userId, MainCallback callback, String message){
    this.serverDatabaseHelper = serverDatabaseHelper;
    this.localDatabaseHelper = localDatabaseHelper;

    context = c;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.callback = callback;

    this.message = message;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    //progressDialog = General.createProgressDialog(context, message);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    /*if(General.hasNetworkConnection(context))
    else*/
    // TODO: test  -  Will only be loading from local (Rest of the program will make sure it's synced up to date)
    localDatabaseHelper.retrieveStudentInfo(userId, callback);
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    //progressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

The main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainCallback{
private static final int REQUEST_LOGIN = 0;

private DatabaseManager databaseManager;
private SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager;

private Student loggedInStudent;

private TextView tempText; // TODO: take this out

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tempText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempText);

    databaseManager = DatabaseManager.getInstance(this);
    sharedPreferenceManager = SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance(this);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginSignUpActivityActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_LOGIN);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_update_info) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginSignUpActivityActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(LoginSignUpActivityActivity.KEY_STUDENT_INFO_TO_UPDATE, loggedInStudent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_LOGIN);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginSignUpActivityActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_LOGIN);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_LOGIN){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            long userId = data.getExtras().getLong(LoginSignUpActivityActivity.KEY_USER_ID);
            Log.d("Test","Logged in, start main activity's sql controller");
            Log.d("Test",Long.toString(userId));
            // TODO: something - get student info to be displayed as default for now
            databaseManager.retrieveStudentInfo(userId, this, "Retrieving info...");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void retrieveStudentInfoFeedback(final Student s) {
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    //Do your UI operations like dialog opening or Toast here
                    if(s != null){
                        MainActivity.this.loggedInStudent = s;
                        Log.d("Test", "Woo: " + s.getPerson().getName());
                        tempText.setText("Welcome: " + " " + s.getPerson().getName());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome " + s.getPerson().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        // TODO: error loading info- do something
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
}
}
```

The program returns the expected data just fine
I can display the data in a textView or toast info about it without any errors
However if i try to send the object retrieved to an intent, the program responds with this error:

```
01-05 12:26:44.027 2299-
3150/studentregistration5.test.co.za.studentregistration5 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #6

Process: studentregistration5.test.co.za.studentregistration5, PID: 
2299

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing 
doInBackground()                                    
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)                                    
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)                                                 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)                                                                                                  
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)                                                                                                     
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)                                    
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void 
studentregistration5.test.co.za.studentregistration5
.localPOJO.Person
.setUser(studentregistration5.test.co.za.
studentregistration5.localPOJO.User)' on a null object reference

at studentregistration5.test.co.za.
studentregistration5.localTransactionTracker
.StudentTracker.get(StudentTracker.java:63)

at studentregistration5.test.co.za
.studentregistration5.databaseHelper
.LocalDatabaseHelper.retrieveStudentInfo(LocalDatabaseHelper.java:87)

at studentregistration5.test.co.za
.studentregistration5.asyncTransactionTask
.RetrieveStudentInfo.doInBackground(RetrieveStudentInfo.java:50)

at studentregistration5.test.co.za
.studentregistration5.asyncTransactionTask
.RetrieveStudentInfo.doInBackground(RetrieveStudentInfo.java:16)

at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 

at java.util.concurrent
.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
01-05 12:26:45.155 2299-
2299/studentregistration5.test.co.za.studentregistration5 
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity 
studentregistration5.test.co.za.studentregistration5.MainActivity 
has leaked window DecorView@ab64a80[] that was originally added here

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:418)

at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)

at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)

at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)

at studentregistration5.test.co.za
.studentregistration5.util.General.createProgressDialog(General.java:28)

at studentregistration5.test.co.za
.studentregistration5.asyncTransactionTask
.RetrieveStudentInfo.onPreExecute(RetrieveStudentInfo.java:42)

at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:620)

at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:567)

at studentregistration5.test.co.za
.studentregistration5.manager.DatabaseManager
.retrieveStudentInfo(DatabaseManager.java:55)

at studentregistration5.test.co.za
.studentregistration5.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:78)

at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)

at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os
.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

The issue occurs when I am tap the menu and click on the update user info item

Appreciate the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Add proper class code . Do not part code into points . Its confusing .

Comment: @ADM Added class code